# Value error: the truth of the dataframe is ambigious (converting masked array to Dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn, netcdf4

I am trying to create a timeseries using the seaborn module and linesplot function. For the plot I have attracted variables from two netCDF4 files as 3D masked arrays. The variable I have extracted is called fgco2. I have found the annual mean values for each dataset and added to a pandas Dataframe.

My goal is to plot these as a lineplot with error bands for both sets of data but I get the following error message for line 58 of my code:

```
hindcast= sns.load_dataset(df_melt)
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I think this error is due to the masked arrays containing NaN values within the dataset, but am not sure. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Full code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import pandas as pd

#extracting values for observations
filename = 'C:/Users/efnel/Historical data analysis/fgco2_obs_ymean.nc'
ds_co2obs = Dataset(filename)

fgco2_obs_var = ds_co2obs.variables['fgco2'][:]

#fixing units to be Pg C yr-1 from mol/m2/yr
fgco2_obs_PG = ((fgco2_obs_var* 44.01) * 49306000) / 10**9

#finding global average of carbon flux
global_average= np.mean(fgco2_obs_PG[:,:,:],axis=(1,2))
annual_fgco2 = np.reshape(global_average, (33))

#Finding anomalies to the mean, positive values show weakening and negative show strengthening.
av=np.mean(annual_fgco2[0:33])
obs_anom = annual_fgco2 - av


#extracting data from model
filename_2 = 'C:/Users/efnel/Historical data analysis/fgco2_hist_ymean.nc'
ds_co2mod = Dataset(filename_2)

fgco2_mod_var = ds_co2mod.variables['fgco2'][:]
#changing units form kg/m2/s to Pg/yr
fgco2_mod_inv = ((fgco2_mod_var * -1 * 31557600) * 1000 * 49306000)/ 10**9
#49306000 is m2 area of 16 and 17 biomes combined, taken from Mckinley 2016

#finding global average carbon flux in southern ocean below polar front
global_average_mod= np.mean(fgco2_mod_inv[:,:,:],axis=(1,2))
annual_fgco2_mod = np.reshape(global_average_mod, (33))

#finding anomalies from the mean for model hindcast
av_2=np.mean(annual_fgco2_mod[0:33])
mod_anom = annual_fgco2_mod - av_2

#setting year range for plot
x = np.arange(1982, 2015, 1)

#transforming numpy arrays into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['Year'])

df['Observed Anomalies'] = np.ma.filled(obs_anom)
df['Model Anomalies'] = np.ma.filled(mod_anom)

print(df) #used to check significant figures of data
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Year'], value_vars=['Observed Anomalies','Model Anomalies'])
                  
 #Import additional working libraries
import seaborn as sns
# Linear correlation plot
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
hindcast= sns.load_dataset(df_melt)
    sns.lineplot(x="Year",y="value",
             hue="variable",
             data=hindcast)

plt.savefig('fgco2_hindcast_anom.png')
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: [`sns.load_dataset`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html) is used to load example data from seaborn's online repository. Removing `hindcast = sns.load_dataset(df_melt)` and using `df_melt` in your line plot instead should work.

Comment: Thanks Alex that did work